# Android Fragment onVisible

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer, android-fragmentactivity

I'm using MediaPlayer class inside android.support.v4.app.Fragment. I want the mediaPlayer.start() to happen as soon as the fragment is in view, so I did this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  mediaPlayer.setDisplay(vidHolder);
  mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
  mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
  mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoAddress);
  mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

}
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
  mediaPlayer.start();
 }
```

Now since fragments are preloaded automatically I have two videos playing simultaneously.
Is there an event like **onCreateView** that is triggered only when fragement is in view?

Answer (score 0):

You should override onStart().

From the Android Fragment documentation for onStart:

```
onStart() makes the fragment visible to the user (based on its containing activity being started).
```

Comment: it seems onStart is also triggered right after onCreateView even before fragment is on view.

Answer (score 0):

Found out myself

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    boolean m_iAmVisible = isVisibleToUser;

    if (m_iAmVisible) {
        Log.e("SHOW", videoAddress);
    } else {
        Log.e("HIDE", videoAddress);
    }
}
```